# Slow compile times on jGRASP -- why?

Tags: performance, compilation, java-7, osx-yosemite, jgrasp

Sorry for a more technical question, but I am stumped now. A few of my AP students this year using jGRASP with Java 7 on their MacBooks (Yosemite) are encountering a strange situation, where the first compilation of the day often takes several minutes to finish. Subsequent recompilations of any program proceed almost instantaneously, as if there were no problem. The next day, the problem resurfaces.

Any ideas what might be causing this problem? I have asked the students to download the JDK and jGRASP and reinstall them, but that does not seem to fix the problem. Other students in the class with seemingly identical machine setups have no issue. So confused???

Thanks!
Roger

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an issue with the file system cache. Have them try entering the "purge" command in a terminal, and see if the problem repeats immediately afterward. I'm not familiar with diagnosing such problems, but that would at least point you in the right direction. One obvious "cause" would be too many applications running (or not enough memory).

If that isn't it, have them compile from the command line for the first compile of the day, and see if it repeats. That will tell you if it is jGRASP or javac that is triggering the problem (I say triggering, because some OS issue is most likely the actual cause).